# write an sql query to look up the names of classes that meets in room R128

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Consider the following schema:

> Student(snum, sname, major,level)
>
> Class(cname, meets-at,room, fid)
>
> Faculty(fid, fname, depname)
>
> Enrolled(snum, cname)

write an SQL query to find the names of all the classes that don't meet in room R128 with the smallest number of students(compared to all other classes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT E.cname, Count(snum) 
    FROM Enrolled E
    GROUP BY E.cname
    HAVING Count(snum) in(
            SELECT TOP 1  Count(snum) cnameCount
            FROM Enrolled E
            JOIN Class C
            ON E.cname=C.cname
            WHERE C.room!='R128'
            GROUP BY c.CName
            ORDER BY Count(snum)
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT cname
FROM class
WHERE room='room128'
OR
cname IN (SELECT e.cname FROM enrolled e GROUP BY e.cname HAVING COUNT(*)>=5);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).